# Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed undefined - google maps

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

estoy utilizando el paquete de **google-maps** en angular, tengo un mapa el tiene un puntero y actualmente con un input de dirección busco el otro puntero, pero sucede que quiero mostrar la ruta.

```
<google-map height="500px" width="100%" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="center" [options]="options" (mapClick)="click($event)" #mapa>
  <map-marker #markerElem *ngFor="let marker of markers" [position]="marker.position" [label]="marker.label"
    [title]="marker.title" [options]="marker.options" (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem, marker.info)" (mapDragend)="moveMap($event)">
  </map-marker>
  <map-info-window>{{ infoContent }}</map-info-window>
</google-map>
```

Este código debería funcionar ya que en la documentación dice que así debo declarar el mapa, pero si lo dejo así y utilizo la propiedad **directionsDisplay.setMap(map)** para trasar mi ruta obtengo el error del titulo, al contrario si lo declaro de esta forma funciona

```
  <div style="height: 500px; width: auto;" #mapa>
    <google-map height="500px" width="100%" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="center" [options]="options" (mapClick)="click($event)" >
      <map-marker #markerElem *ngFor="let marker of markers" [position]="marker.position" [label]="marker.label"
        [title]="marker.title" [options]="marker.options" (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem, marker.info)" (mapDragend)="moveMap($event)">
      </map-marker>
      <map-info-window>{{ infoContent }}</map-info-window>
    </google-map>
  </div>
```

Pero darle click en el buscador me actualiza todo el mapa, hace como un refrescamiento y al final muestra la ruta tal cual, pero no seria lo optimo
dejo mi función de trazar la ruta

```
trazarRutaMapa() {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

    const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapa.nativeElement, {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: this.markers[0].position.lat, lng: this.markers[0].position.lng }
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setOptions({
      suppressMarkers: false, draggable: true, markerOptions:
        { icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png' }
    });

    directionsService.route({
      origin: { lat: this.markers[0].position.lat, lng: this.markers[0].position.lng },
      destination: { lat: this.markers[1].position.lat, lng: this.markers[1].position.lng },
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,

    }, (response, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        console.log('ESTATUS OKEY');

        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert("Fallo el estatus" + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Según vi algunos ejemplos la propiedad **setMap(map)** solo se ejecuta en un **div**

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que sea lo que dices, ¿Ya probaste colocando la referencia en un div?. Si nos vamos a las definiciones de tipos tenemos que el constructor de google maps es un elemento `constructor(mapDiv: E, opts?: MapOptions);` y tu le estás pasando una referencia a un component.

Otra cosa que es importante tener en cuenta es que la ejecución del método `trazarRutaMapa` solo puede hacerse dentro del hook `ngAfterViewInit` porque la referencia que apunta a un elemento HTML solo es inicializada en este punto.

Comment: Como explico en la pregunta funciona haciendo referencia a un div, lo cual no debería ser ya que google-maps, define la etiqueta <google-maps></google-maps> y ahi debe ir toda la configuacion del mapa, como ancho y largo, no he encontrado una solución, ya que al hacer referencia al div el mapa se refresca y se ve feo.